# require works, not existsSync

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I've a problem with the following code:

```
if (fs.existsSync('./my-options.json')) {
  var json = require('./my-options.json');
  extend(options, json);
}
```

`fs.existsSync` can't find the file but, `require` does. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

require is load the file with respect to which current file it is called , whereas fs is load the file from where the server runs. means you have to given the path with respect to server(from which it runs). you have to change the path in fs.existsSync with respect to from server runs.

hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try that solution but it will break the purpose of the script as it's through to load a custom configuration on each dev machine.